# what is the key point in this real analysis exercise? Prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_1a_1+p_2a_2+\cdots+p_na_n}{p_n}=0$

Tags: real-analysis

I worked out an homework exercise of Real Analysis with the clue attached in the textbook.
Can you tell me in this exercise which part is more important?  The conclusion or the typical method ?

In other word, should I focus on recalling the conclusion of this exercise or the typical method which solved it? Thank you!

**The exercise is:**

> $$\text{Let }\thinspace A_n=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n \thinspace \text{ and }\thinspace \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n \thinspace \text{ do exist  and  }   \{p_n\} \thinspace \text{ is strictly increasing} $$ $$\text{ and } \forall n\in N^+ , p_n > 0 \thinspace \text{ and }\thinspace \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}p_n=+\infty \thinspace \text{ .}$$
> Prove that:
>
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_1a_1+p_2a_2+\cdots+p_na_n}{p_n}=0$$

**The clue (typical method) attached in the book is :**

> Substitute $a_k = A_k - A_{k-1}$ ,  then get:
> $$\frac{p_1a_1+p_2a_2+\cdots+p_na_n}{p_n}$$
> $$=A_n-\frac{A_1(p_2-p_1)+A_2(p_3-p_2)+\cdots+A_{n-1}(p_n-p_{n-1})}{p_n}$$
> then use Stolze-Cesaro theorem for the fraction part.

**My solution is:**

> Proof
>
> Because $ A_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$, then $a_1 = A_1$ and $ a_n = A_n - A_{n-1}  ( n\geq 2)$     so      $$\frac{p_1a_1+p_2a_a+\cdots+p_na_n}{p_n}$$
> $$=\frac{p_1A_1+p_2(A_2-A_1)+p_3(A_3-A_2)+\cdots+p_{n-1}(A_{n-1}-A_{n-2}) +p_{n}(A_{n}-A_{n-1})    }{p_n}$$ $$=\frac{A_1p_1+A_2p_2-A_1p_2+A_3p_3-A_2p_3+\cdots+A_{n-1}p_{n-1}-A_{n-2}p_{n-1}+A_np_n-A_{n-1}p_n}{p_n}$$ $$=\frac{A_1(p_1-p_2) + A_2(p_2-p_3)+\cdots+A_{n-1}(p_{n-1}-p_n)+A_np_n   }{p_n}$$
> $$=\frac{A_1(p_1-p_2) + A_2(p_2-p_3)+\cdots+A_{n-1}(p_{n-1}-p_n) }{p_n} + A_n$$     Let $$x_n=A_1(p_1-p_2) + A_2(p_2-p_3)+\cdots+A_{n-1}(p_{n-1}-p_n)  ,$$ $$   y_n=p_n$$ So the
> desired term become:
> $$\frac{p_1a_1+p_2a_a+\cdots+p_na_n}{p_n}=\frac{x_n}{y_n}+A_n$$
>
> Further more: $$x_n-x_{n-1}=A_{n-1}(p_{n-1}-p_n) $$
> $$y_n-y_{n-1}=p_n-p_{n-1}$$
>
> Because known that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n \thinspace \text{ do exist  } $, so let $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n =A$ .  Then the limit
> for $\frac{x_n-x_{n-1}}{y_n-y_{n-1}}$ is:
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n-x_{n-1}}{y_n-y_{n-1}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{A_{n-1}(p_{n-1}-p_n)}{p_n-p_{n-1}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}-A_{n-1}=-A$$
> So by Sotlze-Cesaro Theorem we know that:
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{y_n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n-x_{n-1}}{y_n-y_{n-1}}=-A$$
> So the limit we desired is:
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_1a_1+p_2a_2+\cdots+p_na_n}{p_n}$$
> $$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{A_1(p_1-p_2) + A_2(p_2-p_3)+\cdots+A_{n-1}(p_{n-1}-p_n)   }{p_n} + A_n\right)$$
> $$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{x_n }{y_n} + A_n\right)$$
> $$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n }{y_n} + \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n$$
> $$=-A+A$$ $$=0$$
>
> Proved as desired.

Comment: What is the question ? What do you mean by "key point of the proof" ? Are the $a_i$ positive ?

Comment: @Surb I didn't understand the goal or target of this exercise. What kind of skill should I learn from this exercise? the conclusion or the method or others?  I am new to learn real analysis, I feel the solution of this exercise is  intricate to me.